# how to add CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID to stripe transfer API in c# WebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, stripe-connect

I am issuing a transfer API using WebRequest because instant transfer is not supported in stripe.net.  I have managed accounts and I want to issue the call for my customers.  ThecURL is as follows:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers \
   -u {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}: \
   -H "Stripe-Account: {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}" \
   -d amount=1000 \
   -d currency=usd \
   -d method=instant
```

My .net WebRequest  is as follows:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.stripe.com/v1/transfers?amount=" + amount + "&currency=" + currency + "&method=" + method + "&Stripe-Account=" + stripe_user_id);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeApiKey"]);
       var response = request.GetResponse();

        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I am getting the following stripe error:
“Received unknown parameter: Stripe-Account"

Any help is ppreciated!
Thanks!
hsmith825

Answer (score 0):

You're sending `Stripe-Account` in the data, when you should be sending it as a header:

```
request.Headers.Add("Stripe-Account", "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}");
```